# XDK - open link in browser without using Cordova

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I want you to open a link in my app via browser not in Appview. I ma making my html5 mobile app via xdk. I don't want to use cordova in my app as my app is heavy enogh and don't want to make it heavier because of just one link.
I saw this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.kidzout.com', '_system');">www.kidzout.com</a>
```

But the problem is I must install Cordova InAppBrowser plugin for this to work. Do you have any solution without using Cordova or external plugins? Do you think is it possible at all?

Comment: BTW: using Cordova doesn't really "make it heavier" -- if you are using the "Gold" build option you are getting the core Cordova APIs for free. If you are using the "Lean" option, then your approach makes sense.

Comment: Yes I am using Lean option. Because in Gold option the size of application was 7 MB more. and I guess it was a bit slower in start up loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a link in the native browser(Mobile Safari, Android, etc.) from within a HTML5 Mobile app using the *intel.xdk* API formerly *AppMobi*.

In the head, include a reference to the intelxdk.js file.

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
```

Use this for opening your link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('http://www.intel.com');">Launch in Browser</a>
```

For more information, go to http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jsAPI/device/launchExternal/index.html

Comment: requires Cordova js added to the page.

Comment: It's deprecated now, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a remote URL in your webview and adding javascript is not an option, you can make a patch in native code.

Here I show the workaround for Android:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037737/813951