# What is working code for opening a link from my app using intel xdk

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

What is the code for opening a link in browser from my app, best for updated version of intel xdk and cordova plugin. I am using a cross-website.

Currently this is my code, but ain't work'n.

```
<script>
function join_browser(){
                var ref = window.open('https://www.example.com/join', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
                 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
                 ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
                 ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
            }
</script>



<label class="text-style text-center">No account? <a href="#" onclick="join_browser(); return false;"> Register here. </a>
                                </label>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377913/xdk-open-link-in-browser-without-using-cordova  . Seems you're also cross-posting... https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/debug-solutions/topic/635159

Comment: @Hack-R Yes that was my post on intel community (still no answer). And I already tried the solution the link on stackoverflow you have given. This is for new version of intel xdk. --> intel.xdk.device.launchExternal doesn't work anymore!

Comment: I see. Just for future reference SO doesn't want you to cross-post questions here because they want unique content. Not that I personally really care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using

```
 var url = "http://google.com";
 window.open(url, '_system');
```

Tested on Android and iOS platforms.
Alternatively you can also use InappBrowser plugin of cordova.